# Speech to text android feature

Tags: java, android-studio, speech-recognition

There is a problem with a speech-to-text feature I'm trying to implement.

A button is pressed to begin speech to text feature, but everytime it is pressed, it just displays the toast message instead of actually converting speech to text

Here is the code.

```
public class Speech extends Activity{
private TextView resultTEXT;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.speechtotext);
    resultTEXT = (TextView)findViewById((R.id.TVresult));
}

public void onButtonClick (View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.imageButton)
    {

        promptSpeechInput(); //method call
    }
}
public void promptSpeechInput()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL , RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say Something");

    try
    {
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException a)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Speech.this, "Sorry, your device doesn't support speech to text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent i)
{
  super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, i);

  switch(request_code)
  {
      case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null)
      {
          ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
          resultTEXT.setText(result.get(0));
      }
          break;
  }

}
```

}

Comment: It seems like all you're doing is setting the text on `resultTEXT`.

Comment: How are you expecting it to vocalize your strings, if you're never calling the `speak()` method of the TTS Engine?